# Access every button in a UIView on the iPhone

Tags: iphone

What I want to do is ideally loop through all buttons in a UIView (I have a lot, over 40 buttons), and depending on the tag, change the image that the button is displaying. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: @stefan: pseudocode? Really?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *subview* property of the UIView containing the buttons. For each UIView element in that NSArray, inspect the *tag* property. If the tag matches what your logic needs, change the image displayed in that UIView instance - which in this case is one of the buttons.

Answer (score 11):

I would say use the `subviews` property, as devilaether said, but do an additional check to make sure the subview is a UIButton before you do anything else with it:

```
for(UIView *view in [rootView subviews]) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        if([view tag] == 0) {
            // First image
        } /* ... */
        else {
            NSLog(@"didn't recognize tag");
        }
     } else {
        NSLog(@"view is not a button");
     }
}
```

You could also make your life easier if you stored an NSArray  somewhere with the UIButtons you wanted to iterate over; this would take out the `isKindOfClass:` check. See the [NSObject protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBFBDJ) for more info.

Comment: This works, but the NSLog needs the @ before the string. @"didn't recognize tag". Otherwise code won't build. Tried to edit this but I can't edit small changes like these.

Comment: Good catch - completely missed that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i<numberOfTags; i++){ 
UIButton *tempBtn = [yourView viewWithTag:i];
[tempBtn setImage:yourImage];
```

}